# plot gaussian between points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi i actually have a list of points and i would like to plot a gaussian curve between those points to generate some sort of time series.

For example, here i use a date range

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.date_range(start="2015-06-16 ",end="2015-06-23 ", freq='H')
```

and i would like a gaussian density curve (ie normal distribution) between "2015-06-16" and "2015-06-17". Another one between "2015-06-17" and  "2015-06-18" and so on.

I have no idea on how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by 'adding some gaussian between 2015-06-16 and 2015-06-17'? do you just want some normally distributed random variable for each time stamp?

Comment: @JianxunLi i edited the fp, i hope it is clear now

Comment: By gaussian curve, you mean the gaussian density curve? gaussian random process? or gaussian process regression curve in machine learning?

Comment: @JianxunLi the gaussian density curve yes my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.date_range(start="2015-06-16 ",end="2015-06-23 ", freq='H')

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 24)
norm_pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)
density = np.tile(norm_pdf, (len(a)-1)/24)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.plot(a[1:], density)
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming constant vol and no drift (given your short time horizon), the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

annualized_vol = 0.30  # i.e. 30%
delta_t = 1 / 252. / 24.  # Assuming 252 days in a trading year and 24 hours in a trading day.
initial_price = 100

idx = pd.date_range(start="2015-06-16 ", end="2015-06-23 ", freq='H')
dx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx) * annualized_vol * delta_t ** .5
(initial_price * dx.cumsum()).plot()
```

[image: Basic Gauss Random Walk]

Comment: Hi, thank you but it's not what i was exactly looking for. i just want python to plot the simple gaussian curve between two points. I don't want to generate a  gaussian random process like you did. I'm sorry if i was unclear